# Apache Ranger with Docker Containers

Tags: docker, maven, apache-ranger

Following the instructions at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Running+Apache+Ranger+-++%5BFrom+source%5D+in+minutes of Apache Ranger setup with Docker Containers I get the following error:

```
ranger-base exited with code 0
ranger-build  | Building from /home/ranger/src
ranger-build  | [ERROR] Could not create local repository at /home/ranger/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
ranger-build  | [ERROR]
ranger-build  | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
ranger-build  | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ranger-build  | [ERROR]
ranger-build  | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
ranger-build  | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
ranger-build  | mv: cannot stat 'target/version': No such file or directory
ranger-build  | mv: cannot stat 'target/ranger-*': No such file or directory
ranger-build exited with code 1
[+] Running 2/2
 ! ranger-usersync Warning                                                                                                                             1.1s
 ! ranger Warning                                                                                                                                      1.1s
[+] Building 0.2s (8/14)                                                                                                                     docker:default
 => [ranger internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.ranger                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.81kB                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [ranger internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ranger-base:latest                                                                           0.0s
 => [ranger internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 411B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [ranger ranger 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/ranger-base:latest                                                                                      0.1s
 => [ranger internal] load build context                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 274B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ranger ranger 2/8] RUN update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [ranger ranger 3/8] COPY ./dist/version                               /home/ranger/dist/                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [ranger ranger 4/8] COPY ./dist/ranger-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-admin.tar.gz /home/ranger/dist/                                                        0.0s
------
 > [ranger ranger 3/8] COPY ./dist/version                               /home/ranger/dist/:
------
------
 > [ranger ranger 4/8] COPY ./dist/ranger-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-admin.tar.gz /home/ranger/dist/:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref f281f302-0ccc-4a92-b245-967b05bc8fcf::tubqxeupk3m8mtn4797f0wrsj: "/dist/ranger-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-admin.tar.gz": not found

################### LIST OF DOCKER PROCESSES EXPOSING PORTS #####################


###################################################################################


Now, You can run  access RANGER portal via http://localhost:6080 (admin/rangerR0cks!)
```

I have tried creating the /home/ranger/.m2/repository folder giving permissions of the user and also running with sudo but the error keeps appearing.

Does anybody knows how to pass the error or from where to get good Apache Ranger Docker Images?